# How activeadmin chose correct table name in select tag for belongs_to fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I use ActiveAdmin for my admin interface. I try to understand how ActiveAdmin picks the right name for the table. For example, I have 2 tables:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job

    attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, ...  # other attributes
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :location, :is_active
end
```

When I use ActiveAdmin and create new page for user administrate I add this row in user `form`

```
f.input :job, :label => "Current job"
```

How does ActiveAdmin understand that the `name` attribute is the one that it has to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ActiveAdmin using Rails's convention over configuration convention, also known as opinionated.

Because your User model has a relationship to the Job model from your belongs_to directive, ActiveAdmin is able to determine that you are referring to that relation in your form.  It can tell, for example, that since a user belongs_to :job (has one job), it's appropriate to provide a list of all jobs in a popup menu for you to choose from.  Since you're using ActiveRecord (User inherits from it), it knows that it can ask for all jobs in your database to provide a nice list using Job.all.  It knows how to do this because the convention is that model names are capitalized whereas file names and relations are lower cased.

ActiveAdmin uses the Formtastic gem (https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) to generate forms.  When Formtastic provides a list of objects for a collection (in this case, Job.all), it looks for common methods in the target class to provide human readable text - it will use to_s, name, description, and maybe a few others.  You can also specify what it should use on the f.input line.

While the conventions can be confusing at first, they end up saving a lot of time because you don't have to describe nearly as much to use the framework.